# Can I install the same programm twice so that I can set different preferences for them?

Tags: installation, adobe-acrobat

I have Adobe Acrobat Reader DC on my computer and I set my preferences so that I have a black background and light letters. On rare occasions this is not quite desireable and I want to view a pdf as normal.

It is quite cumbersome to change the preferences for these instances, so I just open with some other program (e.g. Chrome). But I would like to use Adobe for this as well.

So I want to know: Is it possible to install Adobe a second time (give it a different name) so I can choose a different set of preferences for that version?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Adobe designed this particular program to be only installed once.  It is very likely that the same version of Adobe Acrobat uses the same registry keys.  However, you can install multiple different versions of Adobe Acrobat, without having that problem.  Have you tried to install it twice?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no option on get.adobe.com to install an older version. Installing the same version twice isn't possible either. The installation software detects the old one (sees it's current) and skips the installation process.